# Why use type declarations in paretheses for expressions?

Tags: c, variable-declaration

I am attempting to learn C by breaking down some source code, line-by-line. I encountered (what I think are) type declarations within parentheses inside of expressions(?) and I'm wondering why this is done.  Here are the examples that are throwing me for a loop.

```c
static void foo(int a)
{
   (void)a; // Why the parantheses and void inside of it?
}
```

```c
struct bar *a = (struct bar *)calloc(1, sizeof(struct bar));
// ^ Why declare struct bar pointer?
```

On first assumptions, I'd imagine it has something to do with forcing the results or values to match the declaration, but in the case of the function example, why not just do `foo(void)`?

Also, if there is a name for this pattern (because I have a hard time naming or describe what is going on), it'd be easier for me to search for this later.

Thanks!

Comment: C and C++ are **different* languages! Which are you asking about?

Comment: @Olaf I meant C. C++ was just a suggested tag that I went with. I apologize for the confusion.

Comment: No, it was not! Syntax-completion is no recommendation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're c-style casts.  Don't use them in C++.  There's one off-case that requires use of c-style casting in C++ but I have NEVER run into a need in my entire career.

Casts tell the compiler that a variable of one type has a different type.

Casting an expression to `void` tells the compiler you don't care about the result.  This can avoid warnings when you tell your compiler to bitch about everything.

Comment: "Casts tell the compiler that a variable of one type has a different type." - Erm, ... no. It tells the compiler to convert one object to another. C has no reinterpret cast. Type-punning shall be done via unions only, via pointer casting it invokes UB (there is an exception for `char` and `void *`).

Answer (score 2):

The statement

```
(void)a;
```

references `a` and then you don't get a compiler warning that `a` is an unused variable.

The `(void)` is just the required syntax.

You second question

```
struct bar *a;
```

would define a variable pointing to that type of `struct`. But at the same time, you are initialising it with

```
struct bar *a = (struct bar *)calloc(1, sizeof(struct bar));
```

This would be the same as

```
struct bar *a;
a = (struct bar *)calloc(1, sizeof(struct bar));
```

but in C it is arguably better not to cast the return value from `calloc` and other allocation functions. I would write that line as

```
a = calloc(1, sizeof *a);
```

Comment: Why is `(void)` required?

Comment: `(void)` is not "required syntax",  it's a convention that some compilers follow regarding the unused variable warning

Comment: @M.M Actually not required in MSVC, where the plain `a;` is enough. I understood from other posts it was a deficiency.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious (void)something; is typically used to silence compiler warnings about unused function arguments. The "something" part is an expression, and the (void) cast just casts the expression's type to 'void'. 

Strictly speaking, the (void) part is not needed.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks for taking the time to respond to my question. I didn't even think or know that "cast" was the term I was looking for. I'll also look into not casting the return value from allocation functions. That's helpful too.